# Problem using \newcommand

Tags: macros

I am using a chemical notation repeatedly so made this new command

```
\newcommand{\MolCState}{$\text{C}^3\Pi_u$}
```

The problem is that in the text when I type

```
\MolCState and the rest of the text
```

the output is like

[image]

there is no space before "and".
Why is this different than typing

```
$\text{C}^3\Pi_u$ and the rest of the text
```

where space is there without adding anything?

Comment: That is basic TeX syntax, the space terminates the command name, use `\MolCState\ `

Comment: Use `\MolCState\ ` or `\MolCState{}`, please consider to use the `mhchem` package also for better display of chemical entities